# How to suppress marathon accessing logs in "docker logs"?

Tags: logging, docker, marathon, docker-container

I run Marathon as a Docker container.

When I request logs running "docker logs " I see a lot of records related to access events:

```
[2017-04-24 13:05:59,106] INFO 172.25.250.16 - - [24/Apr/2017:13:05:59 +0000] "GET //vdorct2:8080/v2/queue HTTP/1.1" 200 32 "http://vdorct2:8080/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36" 1 (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog$$EnhancerByGuice$$c1e74978:qtp2035387904-37)
[2017-04-24 13:05:59,107] INFO Proxying request to GET http://vdorct1:8080/v2/deployments from vdorct2:8080 (mesosphere.marathon.api.JavaUrlConnectionRequestForwarder$:qtp2035387904-31)
[2017-04-24 13:05:59,110] INFO 172.25.250.16 - - [24/Apr/2017:13:05:59 +0000] "GET //vdorct2:8080/v2/deployments HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "http://vdorct2:8080/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36" 1 (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog$$EnhancerByGuice$$c1e74978:qtp2035387904-31)
```

I can suppress them using *marathon_url/logging* at runtime. But I'd like to do it during installation by adding some parameter that would switch recording access logs on or off. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `switch on | off` while container is running. However, it is possible to disable the logging while start running container using option `--log-driver none`

For eg:
`docker run -it --log-driver none alpine sh`

There is also another possibility to limit the size of the log file using below option

```
--log-opt max-size=10m
```

> The maximum size of the log before it is rolled. A positive integer plus a modifier representing the unit of measure (k, m, or g).

```
--log-opt max-file=3
```

> The maximum number of log files that can be present. If rolling the logs creates excess files, the oldest file is removed. Only effective when max-size is also set. A positive integer.

You can find more detailed information from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#options-for-all-drivers) regarding logging.

Comment: Thanks for answer! 
But this way is only for manage files count and size. It is necessary to supress only one type of messages.
In other words, it is necessary doing with command line the same as marathon_url/logging фе runtime.

Answer (score 0):

After making some survey we found out that there is really no way to solve that problem. It is possible only start marathon with another logging_level which impact to all loggers.